# Can omitting public abstract from interfaces harm bytecode compatibility?

Tags: java, interface, compatibility, backwards-compatibility

While browsing through SO questions, I came accross the definition of `Runnable`:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Runnable {
    /**
     * When an object implementing interface <code>Runnable</code> is used
     * to create a thread, starting the thread causes the object's
     * <code>run</code> method to be called in that separately executing
     * thread.
     * <p>
     * The general contract of the method <code>run</code> is that it may
     * take any action whatsoever.
     *
     * @see     java.lang.Thread#run()
     */
    public abstract void run();
}
```

As you can see, it has `public abstract` in the method definition, which are superfluous and, *as far as I know*, should not be included in method declarations.

I expect the JDK team to have seen this and expect there to be a reason they are still here.

Hence the question, can removing `public abstract` from interface declarations break bytecode compatability? Keep in mind that this `Runnable` technically still has to work even with code written using JDK1.0 java code.

Answer (score 5):

I can't find any better source, but [here's the JLS for Java 1.](http://titanium.cs.berkeley.edu/doc/java-langspec-1.0/) (Maybe [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa286478%28v=vs.60%29.aspx).)

Like every other JLS since then, it states.

```
AbstractMethodDeclaration:

    AbstractMethodModifiers opt ResultType MethodDeclarator Throwsopt ;

AbstractMethodModifiers:

    AbstractMethodModifier

    AbstractMethodModifiers AbstractMethodModifier

AbstractMethodModifier: one of

    public abstract
```

Notice the `opt`. It also states

> Every method declaration in the body of an interface is implicitly
>   abstract, so its body is always represented by a semicolon, not a
>   block. For compatibility with older versions of Java, it is permitted
>   but discouraged, as a matter of style, to redundantly specify the
>   abstract modifier for methods declared in interfaces.
>
> Every method declaration in the body of an interface is implicitly
>   public. It is permitted, but strongly discouraged as a matter of
>   style, to redundantly specify the public modifier for interface
>   methods.

It will not harm bytecode compatibility.

They probably just wanted to be as explicit as possible.